# Same column in two worksheets are aligned differently horizontally

Tags: excel

I am copying a worksheet programmatically by filling in a blank sheet. One column is a dollar amount. In the original sheet, it's right aligned. In the new sheet, it's left aligned. When I do format cells to look at the format, both are Number tab = General and horizontal alignment = General.

What's making them have two different kinds of horizontal alignments? I am assuming it's inferring the data type from the original one. How can I do the same in Excel for the other?

Answer (score 0):

If the Number Format of the cell is General and Alignment hasn't been specifically set to anything, then text gets left-aligned and numbers get right-aligned.

However, you can deliberately set the alignment of any range, independently of the number formatting.

For example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorksheetName").Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B2:C7").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

or

```
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

Feel free to post some code if you need more detailed help.

Comment: but the question is when both are numbers, why would one be right aligned and the other left aligned when both have alignment as General. I don't want to use any code. I can just modify the text alignment. I wanted to understand why Excel is treating them differently. Is there a setting to define a column data type as number (beside the cell formatting option)?

Comment: You can override the General number format with a specific Horizontal Alignment format, using Format Cells or using the VBA equivalents. Once you set the Horizontal Alignment, then the General number format becomes irrelevant. Does that make sense?